# Connecting to a Postgres Heroku DB from AWS Glue, SSL issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-glue

I'm trying to connect to my Heroku DB and I'm getting the following series of errors related to SSL:

```
SSL connection to data store using host matching failed. Retrying without host matching.
SSL connection to data store failed. Retrying without SSL.
Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection attempt timed out.
```

I managed to connect to the DB with DBeaver and had similar SSL problems until I set the SSL Factory to `org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`, but Glue doesn't offer any SSL options.

The DB is actually hosted on AWS, the connection URL is:

```
jdbc:postgresql://ec2-52-19-160-2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/something
```

(p.s. the AWS Glue forums are useless! They don't seem to be answering *anyones* questions)

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm trying to connect to my heroku postgres database from aws glue as well and am running into the same issues.

Comment: no, turns out you need to use SSL connections to heroku's posgres DBs but Glue didn't offer this at the time I posted it. AWS support said that it was on the todo list. I gave up on Glue and use Step Functions for all my AWS orchestration now. Much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and it seems that the issue is that Heroku requires a newer JDBC driver than the one that Amazon requires. See this thread:

[AWS Data Pipelines with a Heroku Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288274/aws-data-pipelines-with-a-heroku-database)

Also, it seems that you can use the jbdc directly from your python scripts. See here:

https://dzone.com/articles/extract-data-into-aws-glue-using-jdbc-drivers-and

So it seems like you need to download a new driver, upload it to s3, then manually use it in your scripts as mentioned here:

https://gist.github.com/saiteja09/2af441049f253d90e7677fb1f2db50cc

Good luck!

UPDATE: I was able to use the following code snippet in a Glue Job to connect to the data. I had to upload the Postgres driver to S3 and then add it to the path for my Glue Job. Also, make sure that either the Jars are public or you've configured the IAM user's policy such that they have access to the bucket.

```
%pyspark
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.transforms import *

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

source_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:postgresql://<hostname>:<port>/<datbase>“).option("dbtable", “<table>”).option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver").option("sslfactory", "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory").option("ssl", "true").option("user", “<username>”).option("password", “<password>”).load()

dynamic_dframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(source_df, glueContext, "dynamic_df")
```